# Can't access class from custom dynamic framework (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, xcode6

My test dynamic iOS framework `XYZFramework` consists of a single class `XYZ`.

However, even after declaring:

```
import XYZFramework
```

I am unable to access this class, with any attempts yielding the following error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'XYZ'
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Found the answer. I had to prefix my class declaration with the `public` modifier. So this:

```
class XYZ {

}
```

became:

```
public class XYZ {

}
```

And, as always, trashing the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` folder fixed any minor complications.

Comment: After I did add "public" to everything, quit Xcode, remove ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData, relaunch Xcode and errors disappeared.

Comment: I forget this part everytime...grrrrr

Comment: Old thread but one note: Instead of deleting that folder, I found that switching my scheme to the framework and running a build, then switching the scheme back to my app and running a build, accomplishes the same refresh.

Comment: "trashing the ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData" did the trick for me, thanks!

Comment: Do you mind posting your test project on github. I am trying to make framework. and I am getting the same sort of issue. classes and func are not accessible in the separate test project that I am creating.

Comment: And also check SDK min. support version and your app main target support version.

Answer (score 2):

If your Framework's class also contained Static and Instance Member functions you also need some more `public` keywords adding.

```
// set the Framework class to Public
public class FrameworkHello{  

   // set the initializer to public, otherwise you cannot invoke class
   public init() {  

   }

   // set the function to public, as it defaults to internal
   public static func world() {  
       print("hello from a static method")
   }
}
```

Now you can access this via your Swift code or with lldb:

```
(lldb) po FrameworkHello.world()
hello from a static method
```

This ensures the Framework's Symbols are accessible in a **Release** build.