# Unable to see public protocol from framework after converting to Swift 4.1

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, swift-protocols, xcode9.3

I have framework in Swift 2.3 which I have successfully converted to Swift 3.3 and it works as expected on Xcode 8.3.3. I can even see the public protocols in it.

After I converted the project to Swift 4.1 and built it, I am unable to see the public protocols in the header file

eg:

```
public class CommunicationManager: NSObject {
       public static var sharedInstance = CommunicationManager()
}
```

Communication manager is not visible in Swift4 framework header files. I tried clearing derived data too and that did not help as well.

I have checked and tried the following links, but none of them helped

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655705/cant-find-the-swift-file-in-framework-header)  [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823542/cant-access-class-from-custom-dynamic-framework-swift)  [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204879/ios-application-doesnt-see-public-protocol-from-framework)

Why are the public protocols not visible?

**Update:**

If I change Swift language version to Swift3.3 in Xcode 9.3, then the public protocols are visible in the headers and the first line of the .h files says this

`// Generated by Apple Swift version 4.1 effective-3.3 (swiftlang-902.0.48 clang-902.0.37.1)`

Does this mean that it will work fine for an app written in Swift4?

Comment: I don't know this will work or not but try `open`

Comment: after converting to swift 3, xocde made all `public` to `open`, which gave me same problem, couldnt see my public protocols. After made all `open` back to `public` they were visible again in the header files