# Unable to create a custom framework with swift 4.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9.3, swift-framework

I have been trying to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49914538/unable-to-see-public-protocol-from-framework-after-converting-to-swift-4-1) problem. So I thought of creating a new simple new framework on swift 4.1.

My code is this:

```
public class TestStupidity: NSObject {
    public static var shared = TestStupidity()
    public func hello() {
        print("hello")
    }
}
```

However even this small piece of code is not working out for me. The public class and it variables dont show up in the header files.

I have uploaded this project on GitHub at [link](https://github.com/amoghvs22/TestStupidity).

Can anyone help me figure what is it that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you including your "framework" into your App?

Comment: `import TestingStupidity`.  I am able to import the framework but there is nothing in it except for  `TestingStupidityVersionNumber`

Comment: I have added it to embedded frameworks as well

Comment: Have you included it in the **Target dependencies** section too?

Comment: why would I need to do that? I thought adding it to Embedded frameworks was enough as it is not part of my app and is not in the same workspace

Comment: I assumed it was in the same **Workspace**, my bad. So you're just embedding the `TestingStupidity.framework` file directly from the build folder of the other **Framework** project?

Comment: yes, thats right

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `open` keyword: An `open` class is accessible and
   **subclassable** outside of the defining module. An open class member is accessible and overridable outside of the defining module. Also add @objcMembers

   **@objcMembers open class ARCompactDeviceInfo: NSObject {}**
2. Go to **Target -> Build Phase -> Headers** add Umbrella Header file(the file with same name of project) file in **Public**
   as shown in picture. Like in my project I've CryptoAPI.h and rest of files hiding
   [Example of Swift 4 Framework](https://github.com/aleemrazzaq/iOSCSR).
   [image]
3. Go to Target -> General -> Embedded Binaries drag your framework.
   [image]

**EDITED:**
@Amogh Shettigar: I've downloaded your project and Integrated with Sample App after adding above details.
[Here is URL](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fDs7hYLigLG0D5iJURgd68wG3x5hXGkj?usp=sharing) for both Framework and Integrated App

Comment: I tried the changes mentioned by you. But the class is still not visible after I import it in my swift app.

Comment: Public is enough to use the class.

Comment: @AmoghShettigar Check my updated Answer. 3rd Point will help you. If work kindly accept and upvote

Comment: @Aleem adding the file to public headers will mean that the entire file along with the code will be added to the `.framework`. I would like to keep my implementation hidden

Comment: @AmoghShettigar Yes this is true, if you're concerned about privacy then only add umbrella header file in Public and rest of file add into project. I also updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Aleem it still isn't showing up in my header file. I have uploaded the code [here](https://github.com/amoghvs22/TestStupidity/tree/master/Tester). Could you please have a look?

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: Check my answer, Under Edited section I practically Implement your problem. Now I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: @Aleem I highly appreciate your help, but I am trying to develop a app in Swift4, importing in Objc app works, but if I build the same framework and add to a swift 4 app then it does not work.

Comment: @AmoghShettigar, If you're trying to create a framework binary that is to be distributed, look here for some great instructions: https://eladnava.com/publish-a-universal-binary-ios-framework-in-swift-using-cocoapods/    Also see my comment in the other answer about the header file

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps and see that it works just fine:

Create new project of type Cocoa Touch Framework call it `Tester`

Add new Swift file called TestStupidity.swift

Add the code from your question to the file:

```
public class TestStupidity: NSObject {
    public static var shared = TestStupidity()
    public func hello() {
        print("hello")
    }
}
```

Add new target to project of type Single View App and call it `TesterApp`

Select the TestApp target and in the General tab, click the + sign for Embedded Binaries. Select Tester framework

In the ViewController.swift file, set code to this:

```
import UIKit
import Tester

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let testClass = TestStupidity()
        testClass.hello()
    }
}
```

Run TestApp and see "hello" in the output.

Comment: This code worked for me thanks. But is there a way where I can keep separate workspace for both my framework and app, as I have it working in swift 3 and would like to keep it that way?

Comment: I have mentioned my main issue in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49914538/unable-to-see-public-protocol-from-framework-after-converting-to-swift-4-1)

Comment: @AmoghShettigar, you keep mentioning a header file. Following my steps above, can you direct me to the header you're talking about? Perhaps the problem isn't what you think.

Comment: @AmoghShettigar, If you want to keep it working in Swift 3 too, that's a completely different situation. For now, The framework and parent app need to be compiled with the same version of Swift.  See discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49922008/swift-framework-problems-with-xcode-compatibility/49922881#49922881