# Swift framework problems with Xcode compatibility

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I have a framework that I distribute to customers without giving them access to the source code, depending on which version of Xcode I use to build it, they get errors like `module compiled with Swift 4.1 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2.3` when importing the file . 
I couldn't find any setting in the project that allowed me to build backwards compatible version of my framework. Specifically the problem is between 9.2 and 9.3, but at the same time this seems to be a common problem, how can I build the framework so that it works with all the previous versions of Xcode?

Comment: Right now Swift 4 haven't got ABI compatibility. You have to use the same Swift version for the whole project. So, use Swift 3 instead of 4

Comment: It is the Swift version used in the project. Build it for the necessary version

Comment: Hello there. That's why a lot of frameworks are supplying different versions based on the version of Swift you want to use (e.g. SnapKit https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit).

Comment: But that's the problem actually, I'm not using swift 4 at all, I guess it's just getting compiled from 3.3 to 4.1 automatically. So both me and the client are using swift 3 , but they are getting this error anyway, not solution there except for building the framework with different xcode versions?

Comment: Look for "Swift Language Version" under your target's build settings. The challenge will be providing different binary frameworks to different users while maintaining a single codebase, as the Swift language evolved between major versions.

Comment: @matt your comment is rude and not very useful. I do know that a specific version of Xcode comes with certain versions of Swift and consequently there is a compatibility mapping between them. I wanted a solution to this problem, but I guess you don't have that.

Answer (score 2):

Until Swift 5 is released with ABI stability, your library has to be compiled with the same version of Swift as the parent app. This means multiple copies out there based on Swift / Xcode version.

Once Swift 5 is released, then you can compile a copy to be used in any app compiled with Swift 5 or greater.